# Logrotate no longer reads symlinked configuration file due to non-root ownership

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, logrotate

We are currently upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS on our ruby on rails application servers, and have noticed that the log files are no longer rotating.

On both machines we have a file `/var/app-name/config/logrotate` owned by our unix user `deployer` which contains a valid logrotate file as follows:

```
/var/app-name/log/*.log {
  daily
  rotate 365
  delaycompress
  compress
  dateext
  dateformat -%Y%m%d
  missingok
  copytruncate
}
```

This is then symlinked into the `/etc/logrotate.d/` directory as `app-name`

On our Ubuntu 12.04 server we have logrotate 3.7.8 which runs just fine. It goes into the `var/app-name/log/` directory and rotates all out log files

But on Ubuntu 14.04 server we have logrotate 3.8.7 which doesn't rotate the logfiles for our application.

When I debug this via `sudo logrotate -d -f /etc/logrotate/.conf` I get the following output:

```
Ignoring /etc/logrotate.d/app-name because the file owner is wrong (should be root).
```

Chasing this down in the code, it seems this change was added for the 3.8.x release stream: https://github.com/demands/logrotate/commit/b8ce386a969c60e5c8ee78023c24a1ba0aab1526

If I change the ownership of the file symlinked to `/var/app-name/config/logrotate` to `root` then it starts to work again. But given this file is part of my application, and created by the capistrano deployment framework we use in this state, I'd rather not have to alter it's ownership, when it used to work just fine.

So are symlinked config files recommended / supported by logrotate ?

And if so, should it's refusal to use my file (owned by `deployer`) which is symlinked into the `/etc/logrotate.d` directory, be seen as a bug ?

Or is there another recommended approach for application-specific log rotation ?

(also asked on [superuser StackExchange](https://superuser.com/questions/793013/logrotate-no-longer-reads-symlinked-configuration-file-due-to-non-root-ownership%20%22superuser%22%20stack%20exchange)))